# Free Will Theorem question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, quantum-interpretations, quantum-entanglement, determinism

The [Kochen-Specker Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kochen%E2%80%93Specker_theorem) says, if I understand it correctly, that the results of spin measurements cannot be predetermined independent of measurement. They get to this conclusion by describing 33 possible measurements whose results cannot all be satisfied simultaneously.

In the [Free Will Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will_theorem), this is developed further by taking two entangled particles sufficiently far away and measuring in 2 of these 33 directions. The proof seems to assume consistency of these results, so my question is this: If we had an entangled group of 33 particles rather than just 2, what would happen if all 33 directions were measured by space-like separated experimenters? The Kochen-Specker Theorem says that results can't all be consistent with one another.

I have very little background in physics so I apologize in advance if I'm misunderstanding something fundamental. I would also request that answers assume little knowledge of physics beyond what I've displayed above, though knowledge of mathematics can be assumed.

Comment: This is a very unfortunate name for the theorem because it does not have anything to do with free will.

Comment: Oh, it does have something to do with free will. Free will is a central assumption to the conclusions that they make. I agree though that the name is unfortunate because you can't actually conclude anything about something that you've just assumed to exist.

Comment: I believe this post answers your question http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54366/three-particle-quantum-entanglement