# Can we realize a super multi-photons entanglement system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, quantum-optics

Can we find a method to generate super multi-photons entanglement by implementing a special operation which can realize the union of two multi photons entanglement systems ? 
For example , there have two ten-photons entanglement system and after operating with this special operation ,we maybe can get a union system of 18(or 20)-photons entanglement.
According to quantum mechanics ,if it is possible to find a mathematical equation to to provide a theoretical basis for this operation ?

Comment: mayeb a  series of operations?

Comment: It's not clear what "super multi-photons entanglement" is supposed to indicate, but [you can entangle multiple particles](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54366/three-particle-quantum-entanglement)