# Can we entangle three or more particles between each other?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

Do you think is it possible to a have a particle A entangled with a particle B and B entangled with a particle C at same time?

Or have something like A entangled with B, B with C , C with D and D with A?

Or a particle can only be entangled with one particle at same time?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible for more than two particles to be entangled in a quantum way?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54366/)

Comment: What does ``$A$ entangled with $B$, $B$ with $C$, $C$ with $D$ and $D$ with $A$''' mean?  Is it something other than an entangled state of $A,B,C,D$ ?

Comment: @WillO I was thinking the same thing, maybe I will open another question. but before I need to better understand the meaning of entanglement because I want avoid stupid questions.